# What are hyperkähler metrics used for?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, motivation

It seems that a lot of effort has been devoted to endow holomorphic-symplectic manifolds with hyperkähler metrics. It started with Calabi [4] with $T^*\mathbb{CP}^n$. Other examples include coadjoint orbits of complex semisimple Lie algebras [3, 8, 10], resolutions of surface singularities [9], cotangent bundles of complex reductive groups [11], cotangent bundles of holomorphic symmetric spaces [3]. More generally, cotangent bundles of complex manifolds have one on a neighbourhood of the zero section [5, 7]. There are also the various moduli spaces (moduli spaces of instantons, monopoles [1], Higgs bundles [6]), the K3 surface, Nakajima quiver varieties [12], and hypertoric varieties [2], to name a few.

I am wondering what is the motivation behind this. If I have a holomorphic-symplectic manifold $X$, are there good reasons to investigate whether it has a hyperkähler metric? Does it tell us something useful about $X$, or is it the metric itself which is interesting?

## References

[1] Atiyah, M., Hitchin, N., The geometry and dynamics of magnetic monopoles.
M. B. Porter Lectures. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1988.

[2] Bielawski, R., Dancer, A., The geometry and topology of toric hyperkähler manifolds. Comm. Anal. Geom. 8 (2000), no. 4, 727–760.

[3] Biquard, O., Sur les équations de Nahm et la structure de Poisson des algèbres de Lie semi-simples complexes. Math. Ann. 304 (1996), no. 2, 253–276.

[4] Calabi, E., Métriques kählériennes et fibrés holomorphes. Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 12 (1979), no. 2, 269–294.

[5] Feix, B., Hyperkähler metrics on cotangent bundles. J. Reine Angew. Math. 532 (2001), 33–46.

[6] Hitchin, N. J., The self-duality equations on a Riemann surface. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 55 (1987), no. 1, 59–126.

[7] Kaledin, D., A canonical hyperkähler metric on the total space of a cotangent bundle. Quaternionic structures in mathematics and physics (Rome, 1999), 195–230, Univ. Studi Roma "La Sapienza'', Rome, 1999.

[8] Kovalev, A. G., Nahm's equations and complex adjoint orbits.
Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 47 (1996), no. 185, 41–58.

[9] Kronheimer, P. B., The construction of ALE spaces as hyper-Kähler quotients.
J. Differential Geom. 29 (1989), no. 3, 665–683.

[10] Kronheimer, P. B., A hyper-Kählerian structure on coadjoint orbits of a semisimple complex group. J. London Math. Soc. (2) 42 (1990), no. 2, 193–208.

[11] Kronheimer, P. B., A hyperkahler structure on the cotangent bundle of a complex Lie group, MSRI preprint (1988).

[12] Nakajima, H., Instantons on ALE spaces, quiver varieties, and Kac-Moody algebras. Duke Math. J. 76 (1994), no. 2, 365–416.

Comment: I don't see it as effort spent trying to endow spaces with hyperkahler metrics but rather as an effort to understand the natural geometry that various spaces carry. Once you ask this question it turns out that various spaces happen to carry natural hyperkahler structures, and from there I see it as an effort understand this phenomenon better by seeing what other spaces share this property.